# How to manage duplicates users in office/dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

We have duplicate users (with the exact same name) in our dynamics 365 environment. One user is Active and another user is deactivated.

There are few reasons applicable for deactivated users.
1. There is no license assigned to the user of Dynamics 365 from office 365.
2. The user is deleted in office 365 and listed as Deleted users.

For distinguishing the user, we cannot change the username as these users are also applicable for another office 365 environments.

So, is there any way to distinguish the users in dynamics 365?

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate them with `windowsliveid` or `azureactivedirectoryobjectid` which has to be unique.

Also `domainname` cannot be same for two AD accounts. When you say same name I would assume First name & Last name which is fine.